# Python script that checks to see if a form was blank

Tags: python

I'm creating a website, and during registration, I query the user for an optional field called admin password. After they hit the submit button, it runs my python script. I want it to be able to accept  their username and password even if they put nothing in the admin password section.

I have this:

```
if form['admin_password'].value == '':
    adminpassword = 'notadmin'
else:
    adminpassword = form['admin_password'].value
```

and then I run the rest of my code depending on what adminpassword is. When I try to run it, I get a type 'exceptions.KeyError'. Is it just a syntax thing?

Comment: Try `if form['admin_passwd'].value is None` That might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up just doing a try catch to figure it out like this:

```
try:
    adminpassword = form['admin_password'].value
except KeyError:
    adminpassword = 'notadmin'
```

Then I do the rest of my checks on if the password they put in was actually the correct password to become an admin or not. This way, it still works if they put nothing because it just sets the space to 'notadmin'.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of admin_password is null, form['admin_password'] raises exception. Maybe you can use like this:

```
if 'admin_password' in form:
   adminpassword = form['admin_password']
else:
   adminpassword = 'notadmin'
```

Comment: This is not quite what the PO is asking. `"admin_password"` is not what is going to be entered, it is an example.